# Hold buffer to rearrange texts

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I don't know the good way to do this (see/awk/perl); I combined multiple chapters of html files and it has the following structure

```
 <a href="#chapter11">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter12">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter13">title</a>
 <p>first chapter contents, multiple
 pages</p>
 <a href="#chapter21">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter22">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter23">title</a>
 <p>Second chapter contents, multiple pages
 more informations</p>
 <a href="#chapter31">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter32">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter33">title</a>
 <p>Third chapter contents, multiple pages
 few more details</p>
```

I want them to reorganize like below

```
 <a href="#chapter11">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter12">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter13">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter21">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter22">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter23">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter31">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter32">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter33">title</a>
 <p>first chapter contents, multiple
 pages</p>
 <p>Second chapter contents, multiple pages
 more informations</p>
 <p>Third chapter contents, multiple pages
 few more details</p>
```

I have five chapters in a html to reorganize them. I was trying to adopt sed hold buffer but that seems to be difficult with my knowledge. I am not restricted to sed or awk. Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Edit

Sorry altered the source file, it also has few lines that doesn't always start either with

```
  <a or <p
```

is there anyway to have script like inverse selection in sed, something like

```
 /^<a!/p/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) twice, first outputting the `<a>` tags, then the `<p>` tags:

```
sed -n '/^<a/p' input.txt
sed -n '/^<p/p' input.txt
```

Using holdspace it could be done like this:

```
sed -n '/^<a/p; /^<p/H; ${g; s/\n//; p}' input.txt
```

Print all `<a>` tags, put all `<p>` tags into holdspace, at the end of the document (`$`), get the holdspace and print it. `H` always adds a newline before appending to the holdspace, the first newline we don't want, that's why we remove it with `s/\n//`.

If you want to store the output, you can redirect it

```
sed -n '/^<a/p; /^<p/H; ${g; s/\n//; p}' input.txt > output.txt
```

To use directly `sed -i`, we need to restructure the code a bit:

```
sed -i '${x; G; s/\n//; p}; /^<p/{H;d}' input.txt
```

But this is getting a bit tedious.

If you have lines starting with other characters, and just want to move all starting with an `<a>` tag to the front, you can do

```
sed -n '/^<a/p; /^<a/! H; ${g; s/\n//; p}' input.txt
```

Comment: worked well by including (bz of mac BSD sed) ; before closing the curly bracket like (sed -n '/^<a/p; /^<p/H; ${g; s/\n//; p;}' input.txt) but how to inline edit to save into the file? this didn't work (sed -i '' '/^<a/p; /^<p/H; ${g; s/\n//; p;}' input.txt)

Comment: Edited my answer. `sed -i` should work, too, but need some restructuring of the code.

Comment: thanks pfnuessel, my source file also has few lines that doesn't always start either with <a or <p, is there anyway to inversely select <a with sed, something like /^<a!/p/ and just combine all lines that starts with <a and place the reset at the end.

Comment: Edited once more. Please try to describe your problem as complete as possible from the beginning on. It might be easier to use an [tag:awk] solution at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Grep works too:

```
(grep -F '<a' test.txt ; grep -F '<p' test.txt)
```

Comment: did the job but how can I output the file? I was trying like this one (grep -F '<a' test.txt ; grep -F '<p' test.txt >final.txt) but didn't complete result.

Comment: sorry, my source file lines doesn't always start with <a or <p :( is there any way to inversely select <a and combine them?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^ *<[aA]/ !H
/^ *<[aA]/ p
$ {x;s/\n//;p;}
' YourFile
```

if a <a href="#chapter to be more exact (and also allow cap and small variation) is not present at begin of the line, keep it into buffer.

if present, print the content

At the end, load buffer, remove first new line (we start with an append so there is a newx line at first keep) and print the content

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{if ($0~/<a/) a[NR]=$0; else b[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (a[i]) print a[i];for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) if (b[j]) print b[j]}' file
 <a href="#chapter11">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter12">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter13">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter21">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter22">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter23">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter31">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter32">title</a>
 <a href="#chapter33">title</a>
 <p>first chapter contents, multiple
 pages</p>
 <p>Second chapter contents, multiple pages
 more informations</p>
 <p>Third chapter contents, multiple pages
 few more details</p>
```